# Hello, can you tell me how to install PyQt4 into WingiDE

Tags: pyqt4, wing-ide

everyone:
     Can you tell me how to using WingIDE to program pyqt4 programs. I don't want to use Eclipse and Eric, because WingIDE is the most familiar IDE I can handle.
     If there is a solution about this? If you have any, please let me know, thank you very much!!!! I'm looking forward your help, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't install any packages into Wing itself, since Wing uses whatever Python you point it at (the latest installed version of Python by default).  Instead, install PyQt into your Python or use one of the PyQt installers, then make sure Wing is using the Python where you installed PyQt.  You can check that in the Python Shell in Wing by trying to import PyQt or looking at sys.executable (after import sys) to see if it's the correct one.  If incorrect use Project Properties from the Project menu (or in Wing 101 Configure Python from the Edit menu) to set the Python Executable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! With your help, I can use wingIDE to deal with Qt !!!